# C++ Gapful Numbers Crashing

Tags: c++, crash, numbers

I was doing this program in which I am supossed to print gapful numbers all the way up to a specific value. The operations are correct, however, for some reason after printing a couple of values the program crashes, what can I do to fix this problem?

Here's my code:

```
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

void gapful(int);
bool gapCheck(int);

int main(){
    int n;

    cout<<"Enter a top number: ";
    cin>>n;

    gapful(n);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void gapful(int og){
    for(int i=0; i<=og; i++){
        fflush(stdin);
        if(gapCheck(i)){
            cout<<i<<" ";
        }
    }
}

bool gapCheck(int n){
    int digits=0;
    int n_save,n1,n2,n3;

    if(n<100){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        n_save=n;
        while(n>10){
            n/=10;
            digits++;
        }
        digits++;
        n=n_save;
        n1=n/pow(10, digits);
        n2=n%10;
        n3=n1*10 + n2;
        if(n%n3 == 0){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm open to any suggestions and comments, thank you. :)

Comment: What inputs does it crash on? What are the correct values it prints out?

Comment: `n1=n/pow(10, digits);` -- Do not use a floating point function such as `pow` for integer-based work.

Answer (score 0):

For `n == 110`, you compute `digits == 3`. Then `n1 == 110 / 1000 == 0`, `n2 == 110 % 10 == 0`, `n3 == 0*10 + 0 == 0`, and finally `n%n3` exhibits undefined behavior by way of division by zero.

Answer (score 0):

You would benefit from more functions. Breaking things down into minimal blocks of code which represent a single purpose makes debugging code much easier. You need to ask yourself, what is a gapful number. It is a number that is evenly divisible by its first and last digit. So, what do we need to solve this?

We need to know how many digits a number has.
We need to know the first digit and the last digit of the number.

So start out by creating a function to resolve those problems. Then, you would have an easier time figuring out the final solution.

```
#include<math.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void gapful(int);
bool gapCheck(int);
int getDigits(int);
int digitAt(int,int);

int main(){
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter a top number: " << endl;
    cin>>n;
    gapful(n);
    return 0;
}

void gapful(int og){
    for(int i=1; i<=og; ++i){
        if(gapCheck(i)){
            cout<<i << '-' <<endl;
        }
    }
}

int getDigits(int number) {
    int digitCount = 0;
    while (number >= 10) {
        ++digitCount;
        number /= 10;
    }
    return ++digitCount;
}

int digitAt(int number,int digit) {
    int numOfDigits = getDigits(number);
    int curDigit = 0;
    if (digit >=1 && digit <= numOfDigits) { //Verify digit is in range
        while (numOfDigits != digit) { //Count back to the digit requested
            number /=10;
            numOfDigits -=1;
        }
        curDigit = number%10; //Get the current digit to be returned.
    } else {
        throw "Digit requested is out of range!";
    }
    return curDigit;
}


bool gapCheck(int n){
    int digitsN = getDigits(n);
    if (digitsN < 3) { //Return false if less than 3 digits. Single digits do not apply and doubles result in themselves.
        return false;
    }
    int first = digitAt(n,1) * 10; //Get the first number in the 10s place
    int second = digitAt(n,digitsN); //Get the second number
    int total = first + second; //Add them
    return n % total == 0; //Return whether it evenly divides
}
```